# React native removing proxy

Tags: react-native, proxy

I am having problem unsetting the proxy settings. I have removed proxy everywhere I could think of.

This is the error I receive:

```
$ react-native run-android                   
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Configure project :app 
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

> Configure project :react-native-oauth 
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.4.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.github.delight-im:Android-AdvancedWebView:v3.0.0.
  Required by:
      project :app > project :react-native-oauth
   > Could not resolve com.github.delight-im:Android-AdvancedWebView:v3.0.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/v3.0.0/Android-AdvancedWebView-v3.0.0.pom'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/v3.0.0/Android-AdvancedWebView-v3.0.0.pom'.
            > Connect to 172.31.1.4:8080 [/172.31.1.4] failed: connect timed out

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 48s
9 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 8 up-to-date
```

What I have done follows:

```
$ npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy

npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

I have checked by `/etc/environment` file.
Checked `android/gradle.properties`

```
$ env | grep proxy
#outputs nothing
$ unset http_proxy https_proxy all_proxy HTTP_PROXY HTTPS_PROXY ALL_PROXY # Still did this for a local bash
```

In the root folder of my project, I searched for proxy using:

```
$ grep -iRl ./android -e "172.31.1.4"
#no output
```

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 6):

Try to Solve it by removing all

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost
systemProp.http.proxyPort

systemProp.https.proxyHost
systemProp.https.proxyPort
```

in *C:/Users/[your_user_name]/.gradle/gradle.properties* file